# How to do a timeseries join in pandas when dates don't match?

Tags: python, join, pandas, time-series

I have two timeseries/dataframes in pandas and I need to take the index from one, and pull the matching value from the other, using last value carried forward.

**Example:**

Starting with frames A and B, I want to make C, which has the same dates as B, but with an extra column showing the last observed value from A before that date.

```
>>> A
        Date   Y
0 2010-01-01   6
1 2010-09-15   9
2 2011-05-01  12
>>> B
        Date  X
0 2009-02-01  1
1 2010-02-01  2
2 2010-03-01  3
3 2010-12-21  4
4 2011-08-01  5
>>> C
        Date  X   Y
0 2009-02-01  1 NaN
1 2010-02-01  2   6
2 2010-03-01  3   6
3 2010-12-21  4   9
4 2011-08-01  5  12
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.asof` function. NOTE that `.asof` only applies to `pd.Series` object with `pd.DatetimeIndex` as index.

```
# must use Date as index
df_A = df_A.set_index('Date')
df_B = df_B.set_index('Date')

# asof
df_B['Y'] = df_A['Y'].asof(df_B.index)

            X   Y
Date             
2009-02-01  1 NaN
2010-02-01  2   6
2010-03-01  3   6
2010-12-21  4   9
2011-08-01  5  12
```